# Nginx name based configuration not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I have set up the Nginx +unicorn for my rails application, it is working while using server name as `localhost`, but not working if I set some other name:

```
server {

listen   80 default;
server_name  testapp www.testapp.com; 

access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

location / {
    root   /home/testapp/public;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

Comment: what error do you get? did you add www.testapp.com to /etc/hosts ?

Comment: Thanks :) Worked after adding it on the /etc/hosts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after adding the namespace on the /etc/hosts file as below
"127.0.0.1 www.testapp.com"

Answer (score 0):

try changing "default" to "default_server" or remove it from listen section, 
configuration itself is correct

Comment: I have changed as you suggested  but still unable to access the app via name.


server {
 listen   80;
 server_name  www.testapp.com; 
 access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

 location / {
  root   /home/sti/public;
  index  index.html index.htm;
 }

Comment: how do you route requests to your nginx server?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you really need the `testapp` in server_name  testapp www.testapp.com;
`localhost` is equivalent to `example.com` so you might want to add testapp.com only.

Here is one from my production env., maybe this helps:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name    www.example.com example.com;
  client_max_body_size 100M;

  root /home/example/current/public;

  # This is a ruby application, deny other common types.
  location ~ \.(php|asp|aspx|jsp|cfm|dll)$ {
    deny all;
    break;
  }

  location / {
    include /etc/nginx/conf/proxy.conf;
    …
```